# pagination with non related tables having different fields in both the table in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4

I want to paginate the records of two DB tables, Table1 and Table2 ,which are not related to each other and both the DB tables have different number of fields.Each query should have some conditions and are joined with some other tables also.

I want to paginate the records of both the table simultaneously so that i can show the data as follows-

```
Row1 = Table1's - name, address,...
Row2 = Table2's - tool_name, quantity,...
Row3 = Table1's - name, address,...
Row4 = Table2's - tool_name, quantity,...
.
.
.
```

If there will be no records for table1 then it will paginate table2 and vice versa.
I want this to be done on symfony PHP framework.Can somebody help on forming the query for this type of pagination.

Comment: Hi @Sitansu, how did you end up it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. As the solution is bit long i am putting the solution in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I end up something like this.

Fetched all the data of different queries and stored into an array and later on cached it.

```
foreach($queries as $key => $query) {
 foreach ($query->fetchArray() as $result) {
    $data[] = $result;
 }
}

$c = new sfFileCache(
    array(
     'cache_dir' => sfConfig::get('sf_cache_dir').'/function',
     'lifetime'  => 3600,
    )
 );
$c->set('myarray',serialize($data));
```

I extend the sfDoctrinePager so that it will find total number of pages, etc. for all those queries.

Than i used PHP usort() to sort the data according to a specific order.

```
usort($data, array($this,'activity_sort'));
```

Then i used PHP array_chunk() to get limited records.

```
$chunkedData  = array_chunk($data, $limit);
$finalData = $chunkedData[$page - 1];
```

Yes it breaks the rules of pagination but at that time i did not got any better solution that this.